# Python JSON Vend API definition

Tags: python, regex, json

I have this code:

```
response = requests.get('https://xxx.vendhq.com/api/customers',
                     auth=('xxx', 'yyy'))
data = response.json()

customer_groups = [customer['customer_group_name'] for customer in data['customers']]
```

Can I do this better?

Example output of complete JSON structure (from Vend docs):

```
{
"customers": [
{
    "id": "18a68b58-ccd7-11df-a32f-4040f540b50a",
    "name": "Bob smith",
    "customer_code": "Bob-U2K9",
    "updated_at": "2010-09-30 20:52:51",
    "deleted_at": "",
    "balance": "0.00000",
    "year_to_date": "0.00000",
    "points": "0",
    "customer_group_id": "6e1dee9e-80e4-11df-b0bf-4040f540b50a",
    "customer_group_name": "All Customers",
    "company_name": "Bob’s company",
    "phone": "555-1235",
    "mobile": "",
    "fax": "",
    "email": "",
    "website": "",
    "physical_address1": "",
    "physical_address2": "",
    "physical_suburb": "",
    "physical_city": "",
    "physical_postcode": "",
    "physical_state": "",
    "physical_country_id": "",
    "postal_address1": "",
    "postal_address2": "",
    "postal_suburb": "",
    "postal_city": "",
    "postal_postcode": "",
    "postal_state": "",
    "postal_country_id": "US"
}]
```

}

My code generates this output of one of the fields:

```
[u'All Customers', u'Annual Members', u'All Customers']
```

Ergo, if I were to refer to "name" I would get this as an example:

```
[u'Customer 1', u'Customer 2', u'Customer 3']
```

I am needing to obtain the Vend example data in that format, and not the data I am obtaining. This would then allow me to do a regex search() against the JSON data from records already held in the SQL database.

Many thanks!

Comment: You talk about stuff like SQL, but it doesn't seem relevant to your actual question. Can you clarify what you actually want, preferably by removing the parts that aren't relevant? I'm also not sure why you give us the code at the top; it doesn't seem like it's part of the question either.

Comment: Please show an excerpt of the original JSON structure (without field extraction) and an example of the data structure you wish to get. Note also that Python lists are not linked lists.

Comment: I would be defining a linked list inside Python, per: http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch18.html. The code at the top was given to see where the JSON is coming from - could I be doing this better? I do talk about SQL, as I need to insert this data from the JSON into SQL - that I know how to do, all I need to do is get it into a format ready to be inserted. And obviously I can't just showing you confidential customer data, so dummy data is needed. Besides, this is the exact output I am getting from the program, except for the censoring of confidential names.

Comment: For full structure, see: https://developers.vendhq.com/documentation/api/0.x/customers.html.